# Basic pricing question. If it costs $12.48$ for a $12$-foot length, how much does each inch cost? how much does $9$ inches cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would it just be

$$\frac{12.48}{12} = 1.04$$

which is the price per foot, then the price per inch would be

$$\frac{1.04}{12} = 0.08667$$

then for $9$ inches it would be

$$.086667 x 9 = 0.78 $$ so 78 cents?

Comment: the title question doesn't exactly match the final question addressed in the body...

Comment: just edited it!

Comment: thanks; I think your answer is correct

Comment: but if you were to multiply .78 by 144 it does not give you 12.48

Comment: that's because .78 is for 9 inches, not 1

Comment: @user104 $144 \times .78$ would be the cost of $9$ feet, not $1$ foot.

Comment: silly mistake, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  Alternatively, since there are $12$ inches in a foot, you could have calculated that there are $12\times12=144$ inches in $12$ feet, so, if $12$ feet cost $12.48,$ then the cost per inch is $${12.48\over144}={0.78\over9}$$

(divided numerator and denominator by $16$), so the cost for $9$ inches is $0.78$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. Well done.

Comment: This *does* answer the question. The question was whether the calculation done by the OP was correct.